# How to adjust picture size to use as much screen as possible dynamically?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, user-interface, web

I am working on a Web UI which will be used for monitoring events, the events will popup on the UI as pictures, these picture will disappear after a certain amount of time. The UI will be opened in full screen on a wall-mounted monitor. 
Now, given a number of pictures N, how can I re-size the pictures to use the screen optimally? The original picture size is 1280*720, the same ratio should be kept when scale up or down, and all the picture should be the same size. 
The target screen Height and Width are variables. The number pictures N will be less than 100. Can someone suggest an effective, easy to implement algorithm?

Thanks to Sorin, here is the code I got, it works pretty well for the problem:

```
function resize(){
    var ratio=1280/720;
    var w=document.getElementById("container").clientWidth;
    var h=document.getElementById("container").clientHeight;
    var n=$("video").length;
    var R=ratio/(w/h);
    var width,height;
    var column=1;

    if(n>0){
        while(column*Math.ceil(column*R)<n){
            column++;
        }
        var row=Math.ceil(column*R);
        height=Math.min(h/row,w/column/ratio)-12;//12 pixel margin
        width=height*ratio;
        $("video").height(height).width(width)
    }
}
```

Comment: css: `element { width: xx%; }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First figure out how to change the ratio. Pictures have a ratio of 1280/720 while the display has width/height. So you'll need 1 by `1280/720 / (width/height)` pictures in your grid to correct the ratio (let's call this number R). Now you need a multiplier to get the number of picture you are showing to be the number of pictures you have. You need to find an M such that (M *floor(M *R) > N) since N is small a simple iteration will do.

So now you are going to show M pictures by M*R pictures in a grid.

All you need now is to scale all the pictures down. To make sure we leave as little whitespace as possible we take S as `min (width / (1280 * M), height / (720 * floor(M *R)))`.

So scale all pictures by S and show them in a grid with M columns and floor(M*R) lines.

This all assumes that 1280 and 720 include any whitespace you may want to leave between the pictures. Otherwise you need to revise the calculations.

Comment: Can you show me some pseudo code to calculate value R?

Comment: `R = 1280/720 / (width/height)`